# ios facebook login button result

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login

I'm new to iOS and Objective-C, I want to execute the login through Facebook so I managed to put the FBSDKLoginButton but I'm not able to get the result via delegate. I followed the official guide but still not working for me.
This is the .h file

```
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton;



@end
```

and this is the .m file

```
//


#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "CreatePartyViewController.h"


@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

@synthesize loginButton;




-(void)alredyLogged{

//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginS" sender:self];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]){
    [self alredyLogged];
    NSLog(@"alredy_logged");
}
}

- (void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton{
NSLog(@"logout");
}

- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
          error:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Login");
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
loginButton.delegate = self;






loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"user_friends"];
loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc]init];




[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@end
```

Comment: use this method..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528948/make-button-touchupinside-fbloginview/31562976#31562976

click this link.

Comment: Doing a quick scan of your code it seems like you're setting properties on it before initializing it. On an unrelated note it would be good to see how you're adding it to the view. And I recommend checking out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#login-button in case you haven't

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you haven't set the delegate of the Facebook button?
You can do that either in the storyboard, by connecting the Button's delegate to the viewcontroller it is sitting on, or by declaring

```
loginButton.delegate=self;
```

in your -(void)viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

Put the delegate FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate in your header file,

```
 @interface YourViewController : UIViewController <FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>
```

And add this method in your *.m file:

`- (void)  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                error:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"LOGGED IN TO FACEBOOK");
    // whatever method you want here
}`